# A thinking riddle

Tags: lateral-thinking

Here is a psychological question. Can you answer this question? Mind it, it's a riddle!

> What is the thing that has no name?

Comment: My dark humor side told me the answer is unborn babies...

Comment: This is way too broad

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a bit more meta than you intend, but...

> Any answer given would falsify itself, supposing we take a 'name' to mean any designation intended to uniquely specify a particular entity.  By defining any such as a proposed solution to your riddle, we imbue it with the very quality we purport it to lack. 
>  Of course, one could take adjective synonyms for 'nameless' as valid, if tautological, responses to the question as phrased.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is too broad, but I think it's the word

> Unnamed